# Order by sum in QueryDsl

Tags: java, sql, querydsl

I've got a table with two columns `left` and `right` filled by this data:

```
left  right
===========
A     B
A     B
C     D
B     D
B     A
A     B
D     C
B     M
N     K
```

I want to select all letters that exists in table and order them by their occurrence count:

```
letter   count
==============
B        6
A        4
D        3
C        2
N        1
M        1
K        1
```

I tried this code

```
SQLQuery<Tuple> union = new SQLQuery<>(connection, new PostgreSQLTemplates())
                  .select(number, SQLExpressions.sum(count))
                  .from(new SQLQuery<>().union(
                        new SQLQuery<>().from(table).select(left.as(number), cdr.count().as(count)).groupBy(left),
                        new SQLQuery<>().from(table).select(right.as(number), cdr.count().as(count)).groupBy(right))
                        .as("union")).groupBy(number).orderBy(????);
```

*Without `order by`*, this code runs OK and result is OK too, but I want to sort result based on sum. How can I do this?

Comment: Can you try with `orderBy(number.sum().desc())` if it is valid? Unfortunately, I cannot make a quick test for it right now.

Comment: @lzagkaretos No. It isn't.